# Facebook share dialog doesn't pick up on og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want to share a link to a website through a Facebook status: http://www.pledgehub.com/d/2/test-fundraiser/

However, while the [Facebook open graph linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pledgehub.com%2Fd%2F2%2Ftest-fundraiser%2F) says that the image referenced in the html:

```
<meta property="og:image:url" content="http://pledgehub-1.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_4060.png">
```

is valid, pasting the link into a status update dialog does not show an image preview, even though running a link through the linter is supposed to invalidate any cached image values on Facebook's end. This has persisted for >24hrs at this point, and I've never gotten an image to display.

**Edit1**: The rabbit hole grows deeper...

I can hack the sharer.php url into showing the image like so:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://www.pledgehub.com/d/2/test-fundraiser/?s=fb&p[images][0]=http://pledgehub-1.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_4060.png&p[title]=Test%20Fundraiser&p[url]=http://pledgehub.com/d/2/test-fundraiser/&p[summary]=Test%20Organization%20is%20raising%20$8000%20in%20Test%20Fundraiser.%20Help%20them%20reach%20their%20goal.
```

but when Share Link is hit, the image disappears.

**Edit2**: Problem can be eliminated on AWS's end; the bare image can be shared with a preview using both the http and https urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a bit of a funny one - the [Open Graph docs](http://ogp.me/) say that `og:image:url` is the same as `og:image`, but Facebook isn't treating it that way.

If you change your first `<meta>` tag to this then it works for me:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://pledgehub-1.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_4060.png">
```

The preview looks like this when I go to post the link:

[image]

The image is pretty huge - maybe you don't want it like this. If you resize the image down to about 200x200 it looks a little more normal:

[image]

You might also be able to achieve this with the `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` attributes, but I didn't try this.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I've gone ahead and reported this as a bug to Facebook.